# How do I fix my memory leak?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have

```
int main(void){
  while (1){
    char *input = NULL;
    char buf[1000];
    int read;
    size_t len;
    read = getline(&input, &len, stdin);

    if (-1 != read){
      sprintf(buf, "%s", input);
      lowercase(buf);; // custom function
      get_command(buf); // custom function already checked for memory leak
    }
    free(stdin);
    free(input);
    free(buf);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Running this through valgrind returns:

```
HEAP SUMMARY
by 0x4022c2: main(prog.c:647) //  read = getline(&input, &len, stdin);

LEAK SUMMARY
still reachable: 120 bytes in 1 blocks
```

Since I freed everything(stdin, input, buf) why is it still giving me memory leaks? and how do I fix this?

Comment: Remove `free(stdin);` and `free(buf);`

Comment: All those `free()`s and not a `malloc()` in sight! You really need to go back to the books - this code has a whole lot of problems!

Comment: And allocate memory for `input`.

Comment: @juanchopanza , Doesn't `getline` allocate memory for it?

Comment: @John3136 I've only just learnt memory allocation and stuff still learning :(

Comment: I the code you've shown, you don't break out of the loop. Do you `exit()` from somewhere in `get_command`? In that case, you would bypass `free(input)`.

Comment: @MOehm yea for this sample case I have it exit(0) in one of the if loops.
If this is the case, how do I free something from the main(void) from a different function?

Comment: `getline`'s advantage is that it will read lines of arbitrary length and allocate enough memory for it. You lose that advantage by using a temporary fixed-size buffer, `buf`. If you have long lines, `buf` might overflow. (Granted, 1000 characters is generous, by why run the risk at all? Just lowercase `input` and pass it to `get_command`.)

Comment: still char *input must be freed (as it is allocated by getline on the first call); you also must test if input is not NULL before calling free (if no line was read then nothing was allocated).

Comment: @MichaelMoser: `free(NULL)` is explicitly allowed so that client code can omit the test. As long as your pointers are either pointing to valid memory or are `NULL`, you are safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, you say that you call `exit(0)` from your function `get_command`. A call to `exit(x)` behaves as if the program returned `x` from `main`. That means that you skip the clean-up code at the end of `main`.

In order to fix this, you could return a value from `get_command`, for example 0 for regular operation, -1 for error or 1 for the end of input. That means that `exit(0)` in `get_command` now becomes `return 1`.

Your `main` loop could then look like:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *input = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (getline(&input, &len, stdin) < 0) break;

        lowercase(input);
        if (get_command(input) == 1) break;
    }

    free(input);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I have fixed some other issues with your code:

- Don't use a fixed-size temporary buffer. `getline` can read lines of arbitrary length. If you copy these to a temporary buffer, at least make sure tat it fits; you've got the `len` information, after all. It is even better to use the `input` string directly.
- Don't start with a `NULL` buffer every time you call `getline`. This will reduce the number of allocations, because new memory will only be allocated if a line is longer than every line read before, which shouldn't be very often. That also means that the `free` should go after the loop.

Comment: It took me quite a while of reading and looking at your code to understand it but it helped me out! Thanks!

Comment: Why did it take you long? Because I've put the calls to `getline` and  `get_command` in the condition part of the `if`? If you feel more comfortable with temporary variables, you can use them instead, of course.